# Google tag manager with AngularJS - how to access variables declared in the head section of Index.html from Angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

In order to implement GTM (google tag manager) in my angularJS 1.5 project, I have declared dataLayer in head section of index.html as below.

```
<script>
  dataLayer = [];
</script>
```

And below is the code snippet to be coded in the angular component to populate the data layer with page values:

```
<script>
  dataLayer = [{
    'purchage_amount': 'purAmt',
  }];
</script>
```

My question here is, in order to populate the (to execute second code snippet, just above) dataLayer how can I access the "dataLayer" declare in head section of index.html from my angularJs's component/controller? Please help me with some example if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a global variable, so you can simply use it in your controller..

Try to `console.log(dataLayer)` in your angularjs's controller

Comment: I have tried it `(console.log(dataLayer)`. But dataLayer can't be found in the controller.